# How to find a point A on a spherical surface given another point B, the distance from it and only one coordinate of A?

Tags: geometry

I am implementing a software which works with GPS coordinates.

Some days ago I wanted to find the distance between 2 GPS points and I easily accomplished it by using the [Haversine Great Circle Distance formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance)

Now i want to do something a little different. I have 2 GPS points: A and B.

I have both the coordinates of A, the distance between A and B and only one coordinate of B.

I want to find the missing coordinate from B. How can i do it?

Depending on situations, the missing coordinate from B might be its latitude or its longitude...so i think that the formulas will be two.

Comment: Knowing the distance from a given point will restrict the answer to a circle around the given point. Knowing one coordinate will restrict it to a second circle, namely a parallel or a meridian. Two circles may intersect in two points, so you have to expect a quadratic equation somewhere in your solution.

Comment: Can't you simply reverse your "distance formula"?

Comment: Yes but i'm having problems when i try to find phi...i don't know how to reverse it to get deltaphi = .......